# Count from columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have `select SELECT COUNT(*),names,names2,whole FROM results GROUP BY names"`;

This select is working = how many names are repeat, but if i add same names to collect from names2 (GROPU BY names,names2) then doesnt work. Can someone show me how to implement it?
I need names and names2 column to count and give me the numbers how many names are there. Thanks

EDIT

```
names names2
John  Michael
Peter John
Michael Peter
Peter Michael
```

I need to find all Micahel in names and names2 and give me a number of it.

Result:

```
Michael 3
John 2
Peter 2
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: can you put some illustrations of what you want to do ?

Comment: pls give expected output u need

Comment: Okey, i edited a post, check it now.

Comment: Why does Peter get a count of 2 when there are three records containing Peter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use two SELECTS for name1 and name2 so that they appear as one column (name2 below name1, not side-by-side), then UNION ALL them and *then* do the count:

```
select x.name, count(*) from (
    select names as `name` from results
    UNION ALL
    select names2 as `name`from results) x
group by x.name;
```

The important thing is the *ALL* in UNION ALL because without ALL it would eliminate duplicates and that exactly what you *don't* want.

Comment: whats "x" group by doing here?

Comment: The x is an alias for the subquery, i.e. the two `select`s. So `x.name` refers to the column `name` from the subquery `x`. Note the `x` after the 4th line. It's just a randomly chosen identifier.

Comment: I got results (numbers) from names and names2 how much time is there, but doesnt show me Michael, Peter now

Comment: So you got only one result column although you used my statement which selects _two_ columns?

Comment: Yes you select and just numbers of it, I need name (Michael 3) now i just got 3 without name.

Comment: Although you typed `select x.name, count(*) from (...` only one column? Then your MySQL must be broken ;-)

Comment: sql = "select x.name, count(*) from (select names as `name` from results UNION ALL select names2 as `name`from results) x group by x.name";

This is a select. 

Results are :

29
30
30
29
29
Without names.

Comment: @user3307783 the query of Perl Dog is correct and should return exactly what you asked

Comment: OMG, @ThomasG, thank you so much. I already thought I miss my dinner... ;-)

Comment: @PerlDog I was about to finish mine when I realized that you posted exactly the same. Bon appetit

Comment: @Perl Dog i got it now, you named names1 and names2 like name, but i was configured like names1 and names2... It is confusing me because i have one column in the middle of names and names2. I need in middle of two. How can can i select that column in this SELECT too (last_name) - this is donest need to be count.

Comment: @user3307783: I don't have the slightest idea what you are saying. Perl Dog's answer solves the task given in your request perfectly and you should accept it. If you have another question now, open another request.

Comment: Thank you @ThorstenKettner. I think he means he has three cols, like `name, name2, otherColumn` and wants `otherColumn` to somehow participate in the select. So many people ask for help on problem X and when solved the say “Thx, but my _real_ problem is X+1”.

Comment: @Perl Dog: That is so true! :-)